# Airflow scheduler asking for password of a user

Tags: linux, airflow

I'm running a DAG by Airflow scheduler but every time I run the command (in Linux)

```
airflow scheduler
```

It asks for the password of my username. It's fine to me if it only asks once when I start the scheduler, the problem is when I enter the password it works but will not run as scheduled in the next day, so I have to start the airflow scheduler again (and it also asks for password).
I have some other DAGs under my username but they are running by scheduler, this issue only happens to this DAG only. Do you have any ideas? Thank you

[This is the log I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr6j8.png)

I'm expecting airflow scheduler only needs to be run once only without asking for password